# Can you use a Flash front end to talk to ASP.NET MVC Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, apache-flex

So, I guess flash can talk to [web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229887/asp-net-and-flash-can-flash-talk-to-net), but can one use Flash/Flex in web pages to post back to MVC Controllers (other than via javascript)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any client (no matter what technology it is using) respecting the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is capable of calling ASP.NET MVC controller actions. They are just normal server side scripts that expect properly formatted HTTP request and send a properly formatted HTTP response.

Comment: So by implication, Flash respects the HTTP Protocol - I've only ever known it to run within a page, thus the question.  I guess the bigger question is how easy/standard that would be - would most flash developers even know how to do this, etc.   If we hire a flash person to do our front-end, are we in for a big communication gap,  is specialized knowledge involved, or is this just a non-issue?

Comment: @sydneyos, yes, most Flash developers should know how to send an HTTP request to the server in order to fetch some dynamic data or whatever they would produce would be pretty static applications.

Comment: So, in asp.net mvc, a controller can accept a model as a parameter (basically form fields named like Model.Field).  So, a post vs a get.  A little more involved than a simple HTTP request.

Comment: @sydneyos, no, not more involved. POST and GET verbs are both part of the HTTP specification, as well as HEAD, DELETE and PUT. In ASP.NET MVC the model binder doesn't really care about the verb unless you explicitly specify it in your controller action by decorating it with the proper attribute (i.e. `[HttpPost]`). It is perffectly capable of binding the model from the corresponding request values (GET request query string values, POST `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded values and even JSON strings in ASP.NET MVC 3 or with a proper custom binder even in previous versions).